# How to listen to click event on a container which contains a Loader which loads a SWF?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, click, loader

I've simplified my problem into the following code.

It's an instance of Loader loading a SWF which is not in the current domain. I added this loader into a container, which is an instance of Sprite. I listened for the click event on the container in order to know if the user clicks the SWF. Looks like it doesn't work out.

So how do I know if the user clicks the loaded SWF file?

```
package  {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends Sprite {

        private var _container:Sprite;
        private var _loader:Loader;

        public function Main() {
            _container = new Sprite();

            _loader = new Loader();
            _loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
            _loader.load(new URLRequest("http://strip.taobaocdn.com/tfscom/T13sAUFIBXXXXtxVjX.swf"));

            _container.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClicked);
            _container.addChild(_loader);

            addChild(_container);
        }

        private function onComplete(event:Event):void {
            trace(_loader.contentLoaderInfo.width);
            trace(_loader.width); // 0
            trace(_container.width); // 0
        }

        // onClicked is never triggered in my case
        private function onClicked(event:MouseEvent):void {
            trace("clicked");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Get that SWF's `stage`, it'll be different from yours, and add a listener to that once.

Comment: @Vesper I tried _loader.content.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doSomething); But looks like it's not working. Does it has something to do with the cross-domain issue?

Comment: Ah, it should be _loader.content.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doSomething). Thanks, @Vesper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked my colleague to help dig into this problem. He told me that it has something to do with the Security issue.

I need to have a `Security.allowDomain` call in order to let the click event on the loaded SWF bubble up properly. Here's the code:

```
    private function onComplete(event:Event):void {
        Security.allowDomain(_loader.contentLoaderInfo.url)
    }
```

Listen for the click on `_loader.content` won't always work. Say the loaded SWF only has a plain Bitmap on the stage. Because Bitmap doesn't inherit from InteractiveObject, it won't respond to click event.

So it's nice to have the click event listener attached to the `_loader` or the `_container` in this case and set the `Security.allowDomain` correctly.